# vim и последовательность синхронных комманд

Tags: vim

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: я использую форматтеры для форматирования кода прямо в **vim** (версия 8), которые, само собой, вызываются синхронно, но в случае если файл большой и его форматирование занимает много времени, а я сразу следом вызываю другую команду (например на сохранение), то происходит очень неприятная вещь - бар, в котором вводятся комманды смещается вверх и, таким образом, занимает 2 линии, но окна с буфферами не перерисовываются. В результате содержимое окон не валидно и при движении курсора вниз-вверх меняется на валидное. Лучше всего это продемонстрируют скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это вообще можно предотвратить/исправить?

Comment: Резонный первый вопрос: почему вы не поставите автоматическое форматирование в `BufWritePre`?

Comment: @Ainar-G а кто сазал, что не поставил? Я использую и то и другое

Comment: @Ainar-G к тому же дело не ограничивается только форматированием - это свойственно для всех долго исполняющихся синхронных комманд, в том числе и когда выполняется сохранение с форматированием (когда сразу за сохраниением вводите новую команду)

Comment: Хм.  А функция `ClangFormat` ваша?  Что-то типа `normal :redraw` в конце пробовали?

Comment: функция моя, нет не пробовал, ща посмотрю

Comment: @Ainar-G ага, то что нужно: я использовал `redraw!` после изменения буфера. Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве решения можно использовать команду [`redraw!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:redraw):

```
                                                        :redr :redraw
:redr[aw][!]            Redraw the screen right now.  When ! is included it is
                        cleared first.
                        Useful to update the screen halfway executing a script
                        or function.  Also when halfway a mapping and
                        'lazyredraw' is set.
```